# Bucharest-Athens-Santorini connection flight and procedures

Tags: connecting-flights

It's my first time when I booked a multi-stage flight, essentially in the same reservation I bought a ticket from Bucharest (OTP) to Santorini (JTR) via Athens (ATH), so OTP-ATH-JTR. So two flights under the same booking reference number (PNR) as Aegean Airlines call it.

Only cabin luggage, no checked-in bags.

Company: Aegean.

The JTR flight leaves after 4.5 hrs after I land in ATH, so plenty of time to go around (I don't know how big ATH is, but it shouldn't matter), but I'm unsure what steps should I take to board my connecting flight in ATH to JTR.

The check-in process, is it the same? 48 hrs before the flights. Will I have to do the check-in for each flight?
After I arrive in Athens, my ID will be checked, then what? Usually, this is the step where I look for the exit signs in order to find my transfer to the hotel (or the place to get my checked-in bags, but this time there are none).

Any gotchas I should be aware of?

Optional: I'm not sure if we remain in "international space" or in Athens we enter Greece to board a domestic flight... not sure if it matters anyway, but nice to know.

Comment: Well, from what I know from tomorrow (19th of april) Greece will lift that restriction for EU citizens.

Comment: Context for my statement above: There was a comment before mine claiming something about some restriction that has been since lifted. That comment has been since removed, so mine appears out of place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every airline and airport are different, but here is the "standard" procedure

1. You check-in online or at the airport. Online is available typically 24 hours before the departure of your first leg
2. At check-in you should get both boarding passes
3. When arriving in Athens you need to clear immigration since you are entering the Schengen area from Romania (which is NOT Schengen). Make sure you have the required Visa/documentation (depending on your passport)
4. Follow the signs for "connecting flights". You may have to go through security again.
5. Find your gate. It's either already printed on your boarding pass or you need to look at the displays in the airport
6. Hop on the plane. Enjoy Satorini

You do NOT stay in "international space" since ATH to JTR is a domestic Schengen flight. Both your arrival and departure areas are "airside" i.e. behind security but they are not necessarily connected.

For more details see https://en.aegeanair.com/travel-information/at-the-airport/connecting-passengers/ and click on "Extra Schengen - Intra Schengen"

Comment: I would add: `1b`: ask at checking if you need to take the baggage and re-check them again in Athens. Custom control may be available only in Athens. And 2 is not always true, but in such case, you have transfer desks in Athens.

Answer (score 3):

Let me add two more things

- Yes, you should get both boarding passes, but sometimes for some reasons you cannot get the second one. Ask where you can get the second one (most likely a transfer desk in ATH, also ask directly when leaving the plane any staff where the transfer desk is).
- If you travel hand-luggage only keep in mind what can and cannot be brought onto the plane (this is of course general, and not transfer specific)
- Also (maybe this hasnt happened to you yet) Sometimes the plane is very full and at the gate you might be asked to hand over your hand-luggage, they will put it in the luggage storage (dont know the word) of the plane and usually you pick it up after landing next to the airplane (if a bus is bringing you to the terminal). Since in this case dont put your valuables inside the luggage (so pack that the valuable can be separated)

Comment: Sometimes the luggage is not handed back near the plane. Ask where and when you will get it.